# creating column names using paste0() inside an lapply() in R

Tags: r, lapply, tibble

i have some data:

```
myData <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~ head(.x, 5L))
```

which i am transforming using an lapply function

```
myDataNew <- lapply(myData, function(x) {
   x <- transform(x, ratio = hp/gear)
   x <- filter(x, !carb == 2)
})
```

which work all fine and as well as intended. However i would like to give different column names, such that every newly created column name will have "an flag".

```
flag <- "calculation1"
myDataNew <- lapply(myData, function(x, flag) {
   x <- transform(x, paste0("ratio-", flag) = hp/gear)
   x <- filter(x, !carb == 2)
})
```

here i have learned that the paste0() function doesnt work inside an lapply(). How can i achieve the intended outcome:

```
myDataNew
[[1]]
   mpg  disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb ratio-calculation1
1 22.8 108.0 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1 23.25
2 32.4  78.7 66 4.08 2.20 19.47  1  1    4    1 16.50

[[2]]
   mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    ratio-calculation1
1 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 27.50000
2 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 27.50000
3 21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 36.66667
4 18.1 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 35.00000
5 19.2 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 30.75000

[[3]]
   mpg  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb    ratio-calculation1
1 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4 81.66667
2 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.40  0  0    3    3 60.00000
3 17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.73 17.60  0  0    3    3 60.00000
4 15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.78 18.00  0  0    3    3 60.00000
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `paste0()` not work inside `lapply()`? Why is this tagged `data.table`?

Comment: Hi, if my answer solved your problem please consider to accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing base R and `dplyr`.

To do this in `dplyr`, use :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

lapply(myData, function(x) {
  x %>%
    mutate(!!paste0("ratio-", flag) := hp/gear) %>%
    filter(carb != 2)
})
```

Or to keep it in base R :

```
lapply(myData, function(x) {
  x[[paste0("ratio-", flag)]] = x$hp/x$gear
  subset(x, carb != 2)
})
```